# How to retrieve html form elements and display the values elsewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am inexperienced so sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm looking around and I haven't found an answer that works for me. I am using JavaScript and I have an html form with one text input. When someone enters a value for that input and submits the form I want to return to the same HTML page but with what they entered displayed elsewhere on the page. Here is my form:

```
<form name="chatInput" action="index.html"  method="get">
        chat:<input type="text" name="chat"/>
</form>
```

I saw something about having:

```
var chatText = document.forms[0].elements[0];
```

But when I try to use this I get [object HTMLInputElement]

Also I would only want to create that variable if the form has been entered once already but not initially. How would I check for this?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: If you're talking about a standard form submission (not Ajax) why would you not do this with server-side code rather than JavaScript?

Comment: You should look into jQuery; it'll end-up saving you a lot of headaches over time.

Comment: You can read about [forms in the HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-form-element). There are also many online resources, such as Mozilla's [Gecko DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLFormElement) that can help to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to re-update the html, I'd recommend not using the form tag.

Instead, I'd create a button with the onclick attribute.

```
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="someFunction()">
```

Then in the JS portion, have something like this.

```
var someFunction = function(){
    var chatText = document.getElementById("this-is-the-element-I-want").value;
}
```

Of course, make sure that the element you are trying to retrieve info from has an id.

```
<input type="text" name="chat" id="this-is-the-element-I-want">
```

EDIT: Code indents and clarity

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I actually wanted to run the function when you hit 'enter' instead of clicking a button but I got that working using the onkeypress parameter for the text input.

Answer (score 2):

```
var chatText = document.forms[0]['chat'].value;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XLeAn/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var chatText = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
```